# Role Middleware Dynamic Parameters Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel

I have a role middleware that passes a parameter to the middleware.

```
 public function __construct(UserInterface $user, RoleInterface $role, MaritalStatusInterface $maritalStatus, CityInterface $city){

        $this->middleware('auth');
        //$this->middleware('role:System Admin'); I changed it to 6 for the id.
        $this->middleware('role:6');

    }
```

My RoleMiddleware is this

```
 public function handle($request, Closure $next, ...$params)
    {


        $roles = $request->user()->roles()->get();

        $roles = $roles->map(function($item){

            return $item->id;
        });

        foreach ($params as $value) {

            if( ! in_array($value, $roles->toArray())){

                return redirect()->action('NavController@home');
            }
        }


        return $next($request);
    }
```

As you can see I it is very tied to `6`. What if I want to add `7`... I want to make it dynamically. My tables are `Users` `Role_User` and `Roles`. What table do I need and how to execute it.

Comment: `$this->middleware('role:6');` where is this script located ? in controller ?

Comment: I have updated the controller. The script is in the AdminController. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you want it dynamically you should have a database for the allowed roles .. then in the same controller you should do

```
$allowedRoles = AllowedRoles::all();
$loop=1;
foreach($allowedRoles as $role)
{
    $roleString = $loop == 1 ? $role->value : $roleString.'|'.$role->value;
    // where value is equivalent to the role of your role id in role database
    $loop++;
}
$this->middleware('role:'.$roleString);
```

then in your middleware you should explode the roleString

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $roles)
{
    $roles = explode('|',$roles);
    $user = User::find($request->user()->id);
    foreach($user->intRoles as $myRole)
    {
        if(in_array($myRole->role_id, $roles))
        {
            return $next($request);
        }
    }

    // Redirect
    return redirect()->back();
}
```